# How can I access the column of a pointer in another class in Parse using the .whereKey() function?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a class called `GarageSale` in Parse that has a pointer column called `User`. I am trying to access the `User` object's `house address` column.

Here is what I am trying to do in my code:

```
let radius = PFUser.currentUser()!["radius"] as! Double
let geopoint = PFUser.currentUser()!["house_address"] as! PFGeoPoint
let garageSaleQuery = PFQuery(className: "GarageSale")

garageSaleQuery.whereKey("User.house_address", 
                          nearGeoPoint: geopoint, 
                          withinMiles: radius)
```

After running this code I receive an error:

> [Error]: Dot notation can only be used on objects (Code: 102, Version: 1.11.0)

Is there any way to access the `["User"]["house_address"]` column without having to call `garageSaleQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{()}`?

Answer (score -1):

No, you can not access that information without actually performing the query. That info is not saved in memory, you must retrieve it from the Parse database. Here is what you would do:

```
 let garageSaleQuery = PFQuery(className: "GarageSale")
 garageSaleQuery.includeKey("User")
 garageSaleQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
 (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
   // da war ein Fehler
    } else {
   // die Objekte sind hier
   //beispiel:
   let adresse = objects!.first.objectForKey("User").objectForKey("house_address")
   // die Adresse drucken
   print(adress)

  }
}
```

Note that the include key parameter must match, exactly, the your pointer column in Parse that points to the User class.